# Is Scala case class backed by a Map?

Tags: scala, case-class

Scala [case classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/case-classes.html) essentially capture a set of fields with helping methods. 
How are case classes resolved? Are they expanded to different classes with fields or a generic class that contains, say, a `HashMap<String, Field>`?

If it's the latter, are case classes with single field more expensive than explicitly defined data objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case classes are exactly the same as regular classes, except that they offer some additional convenience functions.
No, they are not backed by a map. What made you think that they are?